# Como mandar enteros a mysql en flask

Tags: python, aplicación-web, flask

soy nuevo en el uso de flask con mysql y estoy comenzando con un pequeño desarrollo con el cual me acabo de quedar atorado en los parámetros de una consulta. Cuando quiero hacer una inserción en la base de datos, me manda error al querer insertar un dato de tipo entero. Este es mi código, me podrían explicar como puedo ajustar la variable curso para que me permita enviar un entero? 
el error que me arroja es el siguiente: "werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'IdPersona'"

```
@app.route("/add_alumno", methods = ["POST"])
def add_alumno():
  if request.method == "POST":
    nombre  = request.form["Nombre"]
    email = request.form["Email"]
    curso = request.form["IdCurso"]
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO ALUMNOS (nombre,email,IdCurso) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",(nombre,email,curso))
    cur= mysql.connection.commit()
    flash("Alumno agregado")
    return redirect(url_for("MostrarAlumno"))
```

Answer (score 0):

El error te dice que no reconoce `IdPersona` en tu tabla. Debe estar mal escrito

Consejos extra
Prueba con

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO ALUMNOS (nombre,email,IdCurso) 
VALUES (:nombre,:email,:curso)",nombre=nombre,email=email,curso=curso)
```

Asegúrate que el usuario haya insertado una respuesta con

```
if not nombre or not email or not curso:
    falla
```